# Usar una tabla en lugar de multiples html con EmailService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, email

Normalmente hago esto:

Email Service:

```
 public void NewScholarship(Boolean isApproved, String name, String classificationDescription, String percentage, String dateStarting, String dateEnding, String description)
    {
        Subject = isApproved ? "¡Beca creada!" : "No se pudo crear la beca";
        var templateText = isApproved ? GetTemplateHtml("NewScholarship.html") : GetTemplateHtml("Declined.html");


        templateText = isApproved ? templateText
                .Replace("{Name}", name)
                .Replace("{Percentage}", percentage)
                .Replace("{DateStarting}", dateStarting)
                .Replace("{DateEnding}", dateEnding)
                .Replace("{ClassificationDescription}", classificationDescription)
                :
                templateText.Replace("{Name}",name)
            .Replace("{Description}", description);
        EmailBody = templateText;
    }
```

Controller:

```
 using (var emailService = new EmailsService())
        {
            emailService.SetRecipient(student.Email);
            emailService.NewScholarship(false, student.Name, "", "", "", "", model.Description);
            emailService.SetSender(user, model.WithName);
            emailService.Send();
        }
```

Después de esto creo un template HTML para enviar el correo (por cada tipo de correo). Pero mi jefe me dijo que esto no es práctico. Y me dijo que hiciera una tabla y solamente un archivo html y dependiendo de la petición del usuario, el template cambiara los parámetros.

Por ejemplo, tengo un Recovery Password y en mi template Html llamo estos parámetros:

```
{Username}
{URLrecovery}
```

Y como comenté anteriormente, normalmente hago otro archivo Html para mi Create Account, y llamo estos parámetros:

```
{Username}
{Password}
```

Pero lo que quiere mi jefe es que solamente haga un archivo HTML, y maneje todo desde el servicio y/o el controlador. Cómo hago para enviar los parámetros para que mi template cambie dependiendo de la acción? ya sea CreateAccount o RecoveryPassword?

Comment: Podrías pasar un parámetro más para indicar la operación y dependiendo del valor de este parámetro decides el comportamiento de tu plantilla html, podrías mostrar u ocultar partes de tu plantilla html respecto al tercer parámetro que bien podría llamarse Operacion

Comment: esto te puede dar una idea: https://somostechies.com/usando-plantillas-de-correo-en-servicios-wcf-con-handlebars-net/

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con hacer una tabla?, ¿una tabla html una tabla en una, base de datos?

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?